# Bootstrap 3 carousel auto start not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented a Twitter Bootstrap carousel using Bootstrap 3.I am trying to auto start carousel but not working.

my java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$(document).ready(function()  
{ $('#carousel-67566').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true });
 });
</script>
```

And HTML code

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-67566">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-67566">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-67566">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-67566">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/1" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>
                                First Thumbnail label
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/500/sports/2" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>
                                Second Thumbnail label
                            </h4>
                            <p>
                                Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-67566" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-67566" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div>
```

Also I want to stop show arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Do Write the code after Jquery is loaded, Or write it before the body end tag as below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
      $(document).ready(function()  { 
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true }); 
      });
    </script>
    </body>
```

If you dont want to show navigation-controller. just remove this line from your code

```
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-67566" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> 
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-67566" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 Carousel Will start sliding carousel on page load

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 3000});
});
</script>
```

```html
To change how long between slides and loading change the interval number ;)
```